# Webdesign Issue: Table columns have same width

Tags: html, css

The containers in my table all have the same width, they take the width of the container with the widest image. I want them all to have their own unique width according to the image size. Any solutions for this? I use a grid inside every container to get the different squares.

**The container on row 1 column 4 is fine but the one on row 2 is not.**

[Website Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAW9i.jpg)

Grid css:

```
.container {
    border: 1px gray solid;
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: auto 2rem;

    grid-template-rows: 14.2857142857% 14.2857142857% 14.2857142857% 14.2857142857% 14.2857142857% 14.2857142857% 14.2857142857%;
    /*grid-template-rows: auto;*/

    grid-template-areas:
            "main symbol1"
            "main symbol2"
            "main symbol3"
            "main symbol4"
            "main symbol5"
            "main symbol6"
            "footer1 symbol7";
    margin: 20px 5px 10px 5px;
    height: 12rem;
    /*width: auto;*/
}
```

**Full code:**
https://codepen.io/robbeg-immalle/pen/wvGBvXr

Comment: Please show us your HTML, as well as your CSS in the question.

Comment: `The containers in my table all have the same width, they take the width of the container with the widest image. I want them all to have their own unique width according to the image size.` The simple solution to this is to not use table as a design tool. Welcome to 2010 and use `<div>` elements to build `flex` boxes that can do exactly what you require; See https://www.pinterest.co.uk/ as an example

Comment: Hey Robbe, you're making this harder by using tables. Use `div` tags instead with CSS Grid.

Comment: Hi, I now used flexboxes as you guys recommeded. I'm still new to this so I might've made some mistakes. I seem to have the same problem as I had before. The containers in the same column still have the same width, while every container should have it's own seperate width. 

**Code: https://codepen.io/robbeg-immalle/pen/VwaLmWx**
**Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/EMlqsqV**